# Laravel 10 Vue3 Vite4 Inertia [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: i:pgfRef

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I struggle at the moment with the following error:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:41 [
Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: i:pgfRef
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <ApplicationLogo class="block h-9 w-auto fill-current text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200" > 
  at <Link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard" > 
  at <AuthenticatedLayout> 
  at <Dashboard errors= {} ziggy= {url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', port: 8000, defaults: Array(0), routes: {…}, location: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard'} auth= {user: {…}}  ... > 
  at <Inertia initialPage= {component: 'Dashboard', props: {…}, url: '/dashboard', version: '5dd4e6adde169e0e13de6c61cb4b5165'} initialComponent= {__name: 'Dashboard', __hmrId: '8e8f4dea', __file: '/Users/soeren/Desktop/dg-app/resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.vue', setup: ƒ, render: ƒ, …} resolveComponent=fn<r>  ... > 
  at <App>
```

I have googled it but have not been able to fix the error yet. Unfortunately, I also do not know how it occurred. Does anyone of you have an idea what I can try?

App.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import ViteComponents from 'vite-plugin-components'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        ViteComponents()
    ],
});
```

I undid the last steps in the code, but this did not help.

Dashboard.vue

```
<script setup>
import SearchGoods from '@/Components/SearchGoods.vue';
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Dashboard" />

    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <div class="pt-8">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div
                    class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg"
                >
                    <div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                        You're logged in!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-6">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div
                    class="overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg"
                >
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 lg:grid-cols-2">
                        
                        <SearchGoods class="min-w-full"></SearchGoods>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

SearchGoods.vue

```
<script setup>

import { ref, onMounted, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import MeiliSearch from 'meilisearch';

const query = ref("");
const client = ref(null);
const results = ref(null);
const selectedHitIndex = ref(0);

onMounted(() => {
    client.value = new MeiliSearch({ host: 'http://localhost:7700' });
});

const search = async (query) => {
    if (query) {
        results.value = await client.value.index('numbers').search(query);
        console.log(results.value);
    }
}

watchEffect(() => {
    search(query.value);
})

</script>

<template>
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div
            class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg"
        >
            <div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                <h1>Search</h1>
                <form action="#" method="get">
                    <input
                        class="block w-full border-none rounded"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                        type="search"
                        v-model="query"
                        
                    />
                    <button class="mt-2 p-2 rounded bg-black text-white">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: There's no mention of pgfRef or ApplicationLogo that are direct causes of the error, as it can be seen. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Having not worked with inertia for a long time and being a bit tired, I faced the same issue, having no idea why "it didnt work". Well, you have to connect to the php server, not the node server.